# Петька решил противопоставить Кольке Витьку, который ненавидел его (кого?) лютой ненавистью

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Петька решил противопоставить Кольке Витьку, который ненавидел его лютой ненавистью.**

Так кого же ненавидел Витька?

Answer (score 2):

*Его* может относиться к Кольке или Петьке. Строго говоря, однозначного ответа нет, поэтому предложение нужно изменить.
Но если вам нужно понять уже написанное кем-то, то предлагаю считать, что слово относится к ближайшему из возможных "кандидатов" (по-моему, существует такое неофициальное правило). Приходим к выводу, что Витька ненавидел Кольку. Но знал ли это правило автор?